# Why is it bad to pass password values/important info using the $_GET['value'] PHP function?

Tags: php, web-applications

Which is better to use with sensitive information $_REQUEST or $_POST? I'm trying to do this as securely as possible, could anyone see the value with either functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using SSL, then anyone will be able to read EITHER of those with ease. If you want to send information securely, you need to consider a secure transport such as SSL / https://

Answer (score 3):

Passing it through $_GET basically means sending it as part of the URL.

However, neither $_REQUEST nor $_POST are as secure. Encrypt your data before sending, and be sure to salt your passwords.

Comment: a get request would be something like /page.php?user=bob&password=password
a post request is not as obvious - as mentioned though they're not exactly secure!

Comment: You should probably mention SSL.

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended to use post because it prevents bookmarking the url with the password in it or leaving the browser session open.

As with all security it's just a layer - even using POST you could still examine the request with a HTTP Proxy such as fiddler or look in firebug. If you want real security you should use SSL also.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the points others have mentioned, using GET will mean the password will show up in log files, which isn't very secure, e.g.

```
GET http://example.com/login/process?email=tom@jones.com&password=its_not_unusual
```

Your best bet is to POST with SSL.

Comment: Can one still intercept and get the information even with SSL and $_POST?

Comment: @Pete Not in a timely fashion, by design.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally bad to pass important information using the query string as it very easy for a user to modify the variables passed. Post variables are not so easy to tamper with.

I have seen a website where sql statements where passed through the url, and another where php commands were passed and then executed with exec(), this is stupid beyond belief.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` returns as well the `$_POST`, the `$_GET` as the `$_COOKIE` variables. Sending passwords this way is nood a good idea. Try checking the passwords in your php and adding the active user to your `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

That's not functions used to pass something but rather *arrays*, used to access passed data.

POST method should be used and `$_POST` array to access posted data,